# Spring JUnit — как правильно тестировать?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Всем привет! В общем, попал в непонятную ситуацию, я прохожу стажировку в компании и делаю интеграцию с сервисом (через RestTemplate), но проблема в том, что я интегрируюсь с сервисом, которого не существует (это сделано для того, чтобы тренироваться именно в той области, с которой работает компания — банковской).
После того, как я написал метод, взаимодействующий с сервисом, мне необходимо написать для него тесты. А теперь, собственно, сам вопрос: как писать тесты для интеграции с нерабочим сервисом? Мне просто нужно их написать, чтобы они были, но не работали или существуют какие-то заглушки для тестирования такого рода?
Ниже привел фрагмент кода, который мне нужно покрыть тестами

```
    @Data
    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ClientProfileServiceImpl implements ClientProfileService {
    
        private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
    
        public ClientGeneralInfo getClientInfoByGUID(@NonNull String guid) {
            URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(applicationProperties.getClientProfileService().getHost())
                    .path(applicationProperties.getClientProfileService().getClientInfoByGuidPath())
                    .queryParam("clientGUID", guid)
                    .build()
                    .toUri();
    
            ResponseEntity<ClientGeneralInfo> response =
                    restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, ClientGeneralInfo.class);
    
            ClientGeneralInfo clientInfo = response.getBody();
    
            if ((response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) || (clientInfo) == null) {
                throw new ClientException(ErrorCode.PROFILE_NOT_FOUND, guid);
            }
    
            if ((clientInfo.getAccountList() == null) || (clientInfo.getAccountList().size() == 0)) {
                throw new ClientException(ErrorCode.ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND, guid);
            }
    
            return clientInfo;
        }
    
    }
```

Естесственно, при попытки запустить вылетает — org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "###": Этот хост неизвестен (###); nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть следующие пути решения этой задачи:

1. Сделать подмену RestTempalte на mock на уровне исходного кода (с помощью Mockito). Здесь при создании сервиса, использующего RestTemplate, необходимо в конструктор сервиса вместо RestTemplate подсунуть его mock такой, который будет запрограммирован на вызовы определенных методов определенным образом с конкретным результатом. Все параметры надо подобрать самому. Плюсы: легко реализовать. Минусы: решение не позволяет проверить работу сетевой части, проконтролировать соблюдение контракта не получится.
2. Воспользоваться [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/). Для WireMock есть обвязка на java, в SpringBoot придется встраивать самостоятельно. WireMock поднимает самодостаточный отдельный mock-сервер (на выделенном порту), который можно настроить на прием, валидацию и генерацию ответов в соответствии с контрактом. Это долго, это сложно, но это не требует внесения изменений в исходное решение и позволяет полностью протестировать контракт взаимодействия с внешней системой.

Comment: А как в таком случае осуществить подмену в тестовом классе (про первый способ)? Я просто немного не понимаю. Если не трудно, то желательно код

Comment: @uxanxv, вы можете заменить свой `RestTemplate` на `RestOperations`, который является интерфейсов и использовать Mockito. На Хабре есть хорошая статья по Mockito от 18 года.